# Configuring cherrypy for global usage

Tags: python, cherrypy

I'm trying to test cherrypy framework by using example from their site:

```
import cherrypy
class HelloWorld(object):
    def index(self):
    return "Hello World!"
    index.exposed = True

cherrypy.quickstart(HelloWorld())
```

When I run it I get this response in the console:

```
[05/Dec/2011:00:15:11] ENGINE Listening for SIGHUP.
[05/Dec/2011:00:15:11] ENGINE Listening for SIGTERM.
[05/Dec/2011:00:15:11] ENGINE Listening for SIGUSR1.
[05/Dec/2011:00:15:11] ENGINE Bus STARTING
CherryPy Checker:
The Application mounted at '' has an empty config.

[05/Dec/2011:00:15:11] ENGINE Started monitor thread '_TimeoutMonitor'.
[05/Dec/2011:00:15:11] ENGINE Started monitor thread 'Autoreloader'.
[05/Dec/2011:00:15:12] ENGINE Serving on 127.0.0.1:8080
[05/Dec/2011:00:15:12] ENGINE Bus STARTED
```

When running browser locally and pointing to localhost:8080 it works. How can I configure the application so that it responds to a domain name say: `www.example.com`? I want the `Hello World` to be tested in my production server having the domain name, so that it can be accessed by anyone over the world from any location or any computer?

Answer (score 1):

You'll use the static ip for the production server...

```
config = {
  'global' : {
    'server.socket_host' : 'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX',
    'server.socket_port' : 80,
    }
}

cherrypy.quickstart(HelloWorld(), '/', config)
```

Then have a dns entry for your domain, www.example.com, pointed to the static ip.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Yeah, I know this. This will respond to `example.com:80`. I want direct production without any port mentioned like `www.example.com/helloworld`. Also can this handle multiple requests at same time? My website can be used by 100 users at same time, so does it handle multithreading?

Comment: when you browse port 80 is assumed so www.example.com/ will work too.  It can respond to multiple requests and handles multithreading.  Set 'server.thread_pool' : 10 to control the number of threads.  Also, consider proxying your app with a webserver to handle request frequency throttling.  We use nginx with uwsgi and it works nicely.

Comment: do you want apache to proxy requests for your python app?

Comment: I simply wanted to test the cherrypy server in production. Since apache is already there in `8080`, I used `5567` and now it shows `oops couldn't connect to example.com:5567`

Comment: check your firewall.  You'll need to open port 5567.

Comment: I am seeing to the firewall thing. Meanwhile, can you explain this line in your comments `Also, consider proxying your app with a webserver to handle request frequency throttling. We use nginx with uwsgi and it works nicely.`?

Comment: We've seen cherrypy instance get overwhelmed with usually bot requests so nginx throttles any ip which send more than 10 requests per second after a burst of 40 requests.  If you have popular site you may want to do the same.